# Do US universities offer Graduate Paid Internship programs in CS/CSE?

Tags: masters

Do US universities offer Graduate Paid Internship programs in CS/CSE?

That is, studying MS in CSE while working as a paid intern in a company, which is arranged by the university itself?

If yes, do they have any age limit?

Comment: Age discrimination is illegal in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, US Universities do offer Graduate paid internship programs in CS/CSE.
It is called Curricular Practical Training/Optional Practical Training.
But each university is different in accepting your CPT/OPT.
You need to have a job offer in hand, check with the DSO of the university for the dates within which you need to apply for your CPT/OPT.
You need to be atleast 18 years i guess.

For more information you can look this up : http://www.ice.gov/sevis/practical-training/

Comment: However, internships supported by CPT/OPT are usually **not** "arranged by the university itself".  If you want an internship, **you** have to hunt it down and kill it.

Comment: You are right @JeffE
That is why i mentioned we need to have a job offer in hand which means we need to hunt for jobs :)

Comment: Just clarifying for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. I don't know but I don't think so.

Remember though that such "internships" are also known as "research assistantships" or "summer research assistantships" and will generally not be advertised outside the university or department because there are usually more than enough ready and available folks.

I have done something similar in the past but only because I know the professor personally and he offered me the position after a few conversations with him.